# Rails why isn't .build working, but .new - is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, crud

I'm creating a simple CRUD in rails like this:

```
def new
  build_sportist
end

private

def build_sportist
  @sportist ||= Sportist.build
  @sportist.attributes = sportist_params
end
```

and get the following error: `undefined method 'build'` for Sportist in the `build_sportist` method. Since I'm using the build_sportist method for the create, new, edit and update actions, I don't want to set it to `.new`, also as far as I'm aware of, `.new` and `.build` do a very similar thing and this should work.

What could be the possible explenation to this?

Comment: `build` is reserved for building associations, not objects itself, see here for [more](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) info.

Comment: @blelump so I should just stick to `new` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows that there's no `.build` method. If you plan to initialize the `Sportist` for edit and update action, you'd need to pass the id from `params` to get the right model. Then for create, you need a new object.

So for actions that handle an existing sportist, you'd need

```
@sportist = Sportist.find(params[:id])
```

and for actions like create or new, where you need a new object

```
@sportist = Sportist.new
```

These can be in separated methods run by `before_filter` hooks for the concerned actions, or on the action method itself.

If you want to unify these, you can play with `#assign_attributes` to set the posted params and then handle the save on each action so that you control the experience for failures and success.

In my experience, this is the type of encapsulation that isn't worth much as you lose a lot of readability and encapsulate very little business logic.